# Make text of a single line bigger on beamer

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I am using beamer for a presentation and need to create a title page. I have the usual 'title', 'author', 'institution', 'date'. Now ideally I would like to put another line below this that is the same size as the author name (joint work with...). I haven't been able to find whether there are other 'labels' that can be put in the titlepage) that would work, so I just wrote an additional line in the correct frame with the centred text. However the text is small. I have tried a `\big{}` environment but it did not help.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The title
\title[colour-bias cycles]{On colour-biased Hamilton cycles in dense graphs}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[me] {me}
\institute[my university] % Your institution may be shorthand to save space
{
    % Your institution for the title page
    %Department of Computer Science \\
    my university 
    \vskip 3pt
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    % Print the title page as the first slide
    \titlepage
    
    \centering  Joint work with X and Y
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \big is for math.  Font sizes are \normalsize, \large, \Large. \LARGE and \huge.  See also \textbf{...}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\centering  \usebeamerfont{author} Joint work with X and Y` to get the same font (shape, size etc.) as your author name.

(However if your `Simple` theme is the same as https://github.com/zbowang/BeamerTheme then you can safe all the trouble, the author is set in the normal font size)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{simple}

\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


% The title
\title[colour-bias cycles]{On colour-biased Hamilton cycles in dense graphs}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[me] {me}
\institute[my university] % Your institution may be shorthand to save space
{
    % Your institution for the title page
    %Department of Computer Science \\
    my university 
    \vskip 3pt
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\huge}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    % Print the title page as the first slide
    \titlepage
    
    \centering  \usebeamerfont{author} Joint work with X and Y
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```